# bootstrap carousel image responsive but container/item not

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have bootstrap carousel working and the image is correctly resized when the window is made smaller. However, the surrounding container remains the same height it was when it was large.

This is because I have height: 380px in the .item css and max-height: 380px in the .carousel class.

Any attempt to set height: auto; or height: 100%;  which I would expect, might allow the container/item to resize, results in the image disappearing entirely.

Any suggestions here is some simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Carousel</title>

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/carousel-SO.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

  <!--  Carousel -->
  <div class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://tips4java.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/screen-image.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <img src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/contestlogos/logo1-best-uplifting-image.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.nerd-age.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Forge-Quest-featured-image.gif" />
      </div>
    </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
  </div><!-- .carousel -->
</div> <!-- /container -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 4000
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
body {
  color: #5A5A5A;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.carousel {
  max-height: 380px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel .item {
  background-color: #777777;
  width: 100%;
  height: 380px;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 40px; 
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I basically want the grey area (.item) to resize with the picture.
Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7DGjk/

for some reason the carousel part doesn't work, but you can see the effect where the grey .item area doesn't resize.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle

Comment: @Selva There's that fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah Its possible. But no need to write too much of css codes for alignment. Here I use `padding` and `background` property for class `item`. Here the css

```
.item {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808080;
   padding: 5% 0; 
   max-width: 600px;
}
```

here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DGjk/5/).

Comment: Wow.
I don't even know what's going on in that background but it works. Thanks.